# Having an issue with "for" loop - warning message about length

Tags: r, for-loop

So basically, I'm trying to run the Turning Point test of randomness multiple times to obtain a sample of Turning Points (say 30). before that, I run random samples of size 20 from a Normal distribution (0,1).
I need to run 30 times to get 30 TPs.

I can do it by hand, 30 times. However, it would be more convenient and way faster to do it with a for loop but I don't really know where to go from there..

The `turning.point.test()` function requires the package `randtests` to be installed.

Here's my code, which is clearly not good.

```
sample.P=numeric(30)
for (i in 1:30) {
  Zn[i]<-rnorm(20) #Generating random samples of size 20 from N(0,1)
  TP.test[i]<-turning.point.test(Zn, alternative="two.sided")
  sample.P[i]<-TP.test$tp[i] #extract the TP value from the test
}
```

So it doesn't work, why? I've searched for an answer on the Internet, but it never relates to my issue. I don't manage to apply it to my code.

The error message:

```
There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
**number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length**
```

Comment: Check out what it returns with just one call of `turning.point.test()`.  If it's more than just one number, you won't be able to store it as just one element of your `TP.test` vector.  And actually, if you just need to extract the pvals, taking out the `[i]` from your `TP.test[i]` should do the trick.

Comment: It returns a test, so by that I think it's more than just one number. Also, the exact same error message appears when I'm only running the first command to generate random values.

Comment: Ah yes, I should have seen that!  Take out the `[i]` there too, since you're creating 20 random values for `Zn`, rather than just one.   ...so to clarify, take out all `[i]` except what's in `sample.P[i]`

Comment: Oh wow!!!! It works perfectly! It gives me a vector of 30 Turning Points when typing sample.P. That's what I wanted, now I can simulate for 50 values, or even 100.

Answer (score 1):

In a couple of locations, what's being created is something with more than just one element, what R is expecting to see when you do an assignment statement that looks like `asdf[i]`, which denotes a single element.  Since all you need at the end is a vector of TP values, the other quantities within the loop can be changed with each iteration without affecting the result.  So, something like this and you should be good to go:

```
sample.P=numeric(30)
for (i in 1:30) {
  Zn<-rnorm(20) #Generating random samples of size 20 from N(0,1)
  TP.test<-turning.point.test(Zn, alternative="two.sided")
  sample.P[i]<-TP.test$tp #extract the TP value from the test
}
```

or even

```
sample.P=numeric(30)
for (i in 1:30) {
  sample.P[i]<-turning.point.test(rnorm(20), alternative="two.sided")$tp
}
```

Comment: Or even: `sample.P <- replicate(30, turning.point.test(rnorm(20), alternative="two.sided")$tp)`

Comment: and MrFlick for the win!

Comment: Oh indeed, it seems even easier! Thanks a lot Mr Flick